# Context-free grammar for the language L = {a^(n)b^(m)c^(k): m = |i - k|}

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, formal-languages, context-free-language

I have this language `L = {a^n b^m c^k: m = |n - k|}`. 
I know `m = |n - k|` can be expressed in two ways

`1) m = n - k for n >= k or n = m + k
2) m = k - n for k >= n or k = m + n`

Therefore, I get two languages where 
`L1 = {a^n b^m c^k: n = m + k}` and
`L2 = {a^n b^m c^k: k = m + n}`. 
Then I claimed `L` is the union of the two, `L = L1 U L2`.

I don't quite understand how to generate a grammar where one exponent of a terminal is the summation of the other two terminals. i.e, in `L1` you have `n = m + k`. 
Also `L1` can be simplified further to 
`a^n => a^(m+k) => a^(m)a^(k)` so `L1` becomes 
`L1 = {a^m a^k b^m c^k: m, k >= 0}`

Attempt answer for
`L1 = {a^m a^k b^m c^k: m, k >= 0}` 
A grammar G1 
`S -> A|B` 
`A -> aAb|lambda` 
`B -> aBc|lambda`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about computer programming.

Comment: Is there a way to move this to another site? In CS stack exchange or Math perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For L1 you can do it with

```
S -> aSc
S -> T
T -> aTb
T ->
```

and analogous for L2.

Answer (score 1):

**`a^n b^n`:**

Consider the CFG:

```
S ::= aSb | <empty string>
```

This generates all strings `a^n b^n`, with correctly matching exponents. The reason this works is that adding an `a` using this grammar requires adding an additional `b` as well; by making sure that every production preserves the desired property (that the number of `a`s is the same as the number of `b`s), we've ensured (by induction, since the property holds initially, and every production preserves it) that it will hold for every sentence we generate from the grammar.

**`a^n b^m c^(n+m)`:**

If we want to make a grammar to generate the slightly more complex `a^n b^m c^(n+m)`, we can apply similar reasoning: we encode in the structure of the grammar that adding an `a` or a `b` requires adding a `c`:

```
S ::= aSc | T | <empty string>
T ::= bTc | <empty string>
```

Again, since every production preserves our desired property (that the number of `c`s is the number of `a`s plus the number of `b`s), it will hold for any sentence we generate in the grammar.

You can apply similar reasoning to figure out grammars that will preserve the other mathematical properties you mentioned in the OP.

Comment: I understand the `S ::= aSc` and `T ::= bTc` part but can you explain what is `S -> T` in your first production [`S ::= aSc | T | <empty string>`].

Comment: The `|` is shorthand for showing different possible right-hand sides for `S`. The grammar is equivalent to:

    `S ::= aSc;
    S ::= T;
    S ::= <empty string>;
    T ::= bTc;
    T ::= <empty string> `

Where `S` is the start symbol, and `T` is just another nonterminal symbol in the grammar, like `A` and `B` in the original post. The reason we need another nonterminal is to ensure that all `a`s are added before all `b`s are added; if we only used `S`, we would end up generating strings like `bacc`.

Comment: I see, so nonterminal `T` is used to connect `S` and `T` together.

Comment: I suppose you could say that.